# woocommerce Changing category count via phpmyadmin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, phpmyadmin

I have 0 products in the "Uncategorized" category in woocommerce but for some reason, it shows the count as 1 in product/ category. I tried to find which product is listed under that category from PHPMyAdmin but I couldn't find anything that tells me which product is connected to that category.

[image]

Is it ok if I just double-click on the value and change that number to 0 from PHPMyAdmin?
Will that gonna cause errors in the future?
is there a better way to achieve that?

[image]

Please advice. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

if your any product have no category this will be uncategorized by default.

please check your trash and draft might any product already linked with that.

Comment: I checked All empty.